# process time response rest api

Tags: c#, api, rest, time, response

I want to create REST API client that can process the time of any response that I get from the server.

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
// client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);

var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("name", "value"); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method
request.AddUrlSegment("id", "123"); // replaces matching token in request.Resource

// easily add HTTP Headers
request.AddHeader("header", "value");

// add files to upload (works with compatible verbs)
request.AddFile(path);

// execute the request
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

for example, I took example code, I get the response in the same line of the send the request.

Should I run another thread to count the time, or there is another way?

Comment: Are you just looking to measure the time it takes to call this service?  If so just use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.

Comment: i want to count the time from the send request untill i get the response, its can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the elapsed time for a code block you can measure it by wrapping it with a System.Diagnostic.Stopwatch.  ElapsedMilliseconds gives you ms or you can use the Elapsed property to get back a Timespan object.  For example:

```
// Start a new stopwatch timer.
var timePerParse = Stopwatch.StartNew();

// code for operation you want to measure

timePerParse.Stop();
var elapsedMS = timePerParse.ElapsedMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine(elapsedMS);
```